# How can I convert .csr into .pem file format as I have to submit csr in pem format

Tags: private-key, pem, csr

I have to submit CSR in pem format.

I have generated CSR using OpenSSL but got stuck in converting it into PEM format.

I have to obtain example - `csr.pem` from `example.csr`. How it can be done?

Comment: Please do not generate multiple accounts just to ask the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56207946/238704) over and over. This is an abuse of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

OpenSSL creates CSRs in PEM format by default.

If you generated the CSR *without* the `-outform` option, the CSR will already be in PEM format.

If you did use the `-outform DER` option, you can convert with:

```
openssl req -inform DER -in <original CSR file> -out <converted CSR file>
```

The `.pem` file extension is just a name.  If the file is in PEM format, simply change the extension on the file from `.csr` to `.pem`.

Comment: The .csr starts with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----` and is thus not recognized by programs like NGINX which expect `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`.

Comment: @Marc - that's expected.  The first is a request, the latter a certificate.  You convert your request to a certificate by having a Certification Authority certify the request for you.

Comment: Yep, I was being impatient and hoping I could just remove " REQUEST" and use the .csr as an unsigned .pem until it was signed. No luck however - Nginx did not like it. Can you convert a .csr to an unsigned certificate (.pem)?

Comment: @Marc - if it's not signed, it's not a certificate :-).  You can self-sign a request though.